# Azure Monitor doesn't list all my subscriptions when adding new resource alert

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor

I am in Azure Monitor, I select the subscription filter to view my existing alerts.
I then click add new alert, select the scope / resources I want to create the rule for, but I am not seeing all my subscriptions in the drop down.

Am I missing a permission? I am already having the 'contributor' role for the subscription that is missing.

[image: Azure Monitor screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Azure, navigate to **Subscriptions**, then click on the "global subscriptions filter" link. Under "Default Subscription filter" dropdown, select the subscriptions you wish to see in the drop down.

Comment: No one in my whole team knew how to resolve that, so thank you for your amazing work.